# An if statement to send an email in Django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, logic

I'm trying to make it so that this email will send only if the boolean field is true. Unfortunately, I'm constantly getting invalid syntax errors.

in models.py

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    has_responded = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    confirmed = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
```

in views.py

```
def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
    item.confirmed = True
    item.save()
    confirm_title = 'Purchase Order %s Confirmed' % item.product
    send_mail(confirm_title, 'Check the Product Order System to see the updated list.', 'myemail@gmail.com',['youremail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponse('Product  %s  confirmed' % item.product )
```

I would like to make it where has_responded is defaulted to True. And then do an if statement where def confirm will only perform when has_responded is True. At the end of the def, I want to make has_responded to false. Therefore, it'll only perform once. unfortunately, I'm constantly getting errors and I have no idea why. The code above all works, but when I implement the if statement it just falls apart.

EDIT:

This is the code giving me the errors

```
  def confirm(request, itemnum):
     item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number = itemnum)
     if item.has_responded == True
         item.confirmed = True
         item.save()
         confirm_title = 'Purchase Order %s Confirmed' % item.product
         send_mail(confirm_title, 'Check the Product Order System to see the updated list.', 'myemail@gmail.com',['youremail@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
         return HttpResponse('Product  %s  confirmed' % item.product )
         item.has_responded = False
```

Comment: Post the original code with your `if` statement and traceback of error

Comment: Please show the code that gives you the error.

Comment: Added the code that is giving me errors. Apologies for not including it in the original post.

Comment: what is the syntax error you are getting (stack trace) ?

Comment: Also you need to set `item.has_responded = False` before `return` statement otherwise that line of code will never going to execute. Kindly post the original error :/

Comment: the error is invalid syntax (views.py, line 11) which is the      if item.has_responded == True

Comment: You are missing a `:` after `if item.has_responded == True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting the `:` after `if item.has_responded == True`. It should be:

```
if item.has_responded == True:
```

Also there are few more bugs in your code:

1. You need to move `item.has_responded = False` before `return` statement otherwise that line of code is not going to execute
2. Send an appropriate `HttpResponse` when `item.has_responded = False`

Comment: Thank you so much! So frustrating when it's a small thing such as the : and also #1 too. I apologize about the badly worded post. I was frustrated and in a rush.